# Hidden push notification not working on Android

Tags: codenameone

According to the Developer Guide, type 3 push notifications work as follow:

> This push will result in our push() callback being fired twice; once with the alert message, and once with the hidden content. When it is fired with the alert message, Display.getInstance().getProperty("pushType") will report a type of "1". When it is fired with the JSON hidden content, it will report a push type of "2".

This is true for the simulator, but on Android, Display.getInstance().getProperty("pushType", "") always returns 3, on both calls.

Comment: If it doesn't match the documentation please file a bug with these details and we'll look into it. Please also include details about the device you tried and the test case just to be sure.